# Why can a Java generic class implement a method of a generic interface with Object parameter?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Here's the Java code:

```
public interface myInterface<T> {
    void doSomething(T yes);
}

private static class myInterfaceImpl<T> implements myInterface<T>{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(Object yes) {

    }
}
```

This thing does compile even though I think the class doesn't override the method from the interface. By type inference I would assume that the type parameter T is always equal to Object since the class implements the method from interface where it clearly states Object as a parameter. The version with (T yes) in overriding method also works, but that is obvious to me. Can you please tell me why is that the case with the example I presented?

Thank you.

Comment: *I think the class doesn't override the method from the interface* -- why do you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have probably found the [answer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html):

During the type erasure process, the Java compiler erases all type parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.

Consider the following generic class that represents a node in a singly linked list:

```
public class Node<T> {

    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

Because the type parameter T is unbounded, the Java compiler replaces it with Object:

```
public class Node {

    private Object data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Object data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Object getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

In the following example, the generic Node class uses a bounded type parameter:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

The Java compiler replaces the bounded type parameter T with the first bound class, Comparable:

```
public class Node {

    private Comparable data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Comparable data, Node next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Comparable getData() { return data; }
    // ...
}
```

Thanks @Oleksandr for that.

Answer (score 4):

This is where type erasure, the mechanism used by Java for backwards compatibility when introducing generics in JDK 1.5, makes things a little counter-intuitive.

Normally one would expect that the signature of an overriding method must match exactly.  That is not quite the case.  While matching a signature exactly will certainly override the method, the *erasure* of the signature will also override the method.  The [JLS, Section 8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1), states:

> An instance method m<sub>C</sub> declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method m<sub>A</sub> declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:

--snip

> The signature of m<sub>C</sub> is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m<sub>A</sub>.

And [section 8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) states:

> The signature of a method m<sub>1</sub> is a *subsignature* of the signature of a method m<sub>2</sub> if either:
>
> - m<sub>2</sub> has the same signature as m<sub>1</sub>, or
> - the signature of m<sub>1</sub> is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m<sub>2</sub>.

Because the erasure of `T` is `Object`, it is allowed to override (here implement) the method with a method that takes `Object`.  If you place an upper bound on `T` in the interface, then you can no longer override the method with `Object`; it must be that upper bound, which is the erasure.

```
// Example of erasure with upper bound
interface myInterface<T extends Number> {
    void doSomething(T yes);
}

class myInterfaceImpl<T extends Number> implements myInterface<T>{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(Number yes) {

    }
}
```

Note that parameter contravariance is not allowed here.  With an upper bound, you *cannot* override `doSomething` with a method taking a supertype of the parameter type, e.g. `Object`.

```
// A compiler error occurs here when the erasure is Number.
@Override
public void doSomething(Object yes) {

}
```

Comment: This is perfect explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain about the contravariance? It's normally permitted for an override to accept a supertype of the overridden method.

Comment: @chrylis Yes.  Java allows return type covariance, but not parameter type contravariance in overridinig methods.  The compiler would treat it as an overload, not an override.  The `@Override` annotation will produce a compiler error, and unless the class is abstract, it will produce a second error about an unimplemented method.

Answer (score 1):

So you stumbled upon Covariance and Contravariance.
Lets say you have:

```
IMyInterface<T> {
  void foo(T o);
}
```

and you implement

```
class A implements IMyInterface<Integer> {
  void foo(Integer o) { ... }
}
```

you could also do either write:

```
class A implements IMyInterface<Integer> {
  void foo(Number o) { ... }
}

class A implements IMyInterface<Integer> {
  void foo(Object o) { ... }
}
```

since the **param o of type T** is guaranteed to be Integer
-> **o** is also guaranteed to be Number or Object
-> because Integer extends Number extends Object

so you are weakening the type!
This is what your code does.